# How to estimate this expectation involving two binomial random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability, expectations, binomial-cdf

*X* and *Y* are two independent binomial random variables where *X*~ B(K_1, q), *Y*~ B(K_0, p), (Note: p+q is not necessarily equal to 1). I am wondering how to compute the following expectation (the expectation is taken over random variable *X*): 
E[*X* Pr(*Y* >= *X*q/p)] = \sum_{t=0}^{K_1} t Pr(*Y* >= tq/p) Pr(*X*=t). Or at least give an upper and lower bound.

Comment: Not a coding question; I vote to migrate to Cross Validated.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks! I have moved the question there.